# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: java, class, controller, salesforce, apex

please help me with my code, Im new to Java/SF and I didn't understand the whole code.

The code below should return the three values of the people which are younger than 18, between 18 to 30 and older.

I want to learn the coding and I comment all lines, if something wrong, please correct me.

At the moment I get the error:

System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.testfor1_c.getEZRen: line 18, column 1
Class.testfor1_c.: line 4, column 1

```
public class testfor1_c {

public testfor1_c(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) { 
    getEZRen();
}

public Integer Count_u18 {get; set;} // variable for people < 18
public Integer Count_1830 {get; set;} // variable for people >=18 AND <30
public Integer Count_g30 {get; set;} // variable for people >30

public void getEZRen() {

List<Einzelrisiko__c> EZRList = [SELECT Alter__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c]; // create List EZRList with the information Alter__c of all people

FOR (Einzelrisiko__c EZR : EZRList) {  // Loop thru the all people

    IF(EZR.Alter__c < 18) { Count_u18++; } // if Alter__c < 18 variable Count_u18 increase
    IF(EZR.Alter__c >= 18 && EZR.Alter__c <=30) { Count_1830++; } // if Alter__c >=18 AND <=30 variable Count_1830 increase
    IF(EZR.Alter__c > 30) { Count_g30++; } // if Alter__c > 30 variable Count_g30 increase

}

}

}

<apex:page standardcontroller="account" extensions="testfor1_c">

Anzahl {!Count_u18} // show the value of people <18
Anzahl {!Count_1830} // show the value of people >=18 AND <=30
Anzahl {!Count_g30} // show the value of people >30

</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance,
peX

Answer (score 0):

IF(EZR.Alter__c >= 18 && EZR.Alter__c <=30) { Count_1830++; }

At this line you have a null value. you must use  check befor comparing in if block.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with "check"? Im new to Java and Salesforce, please.

Comment: Means EZR.Alter__c is null at some point you have to check it for null. like u can use if(EZR.Alter__c!=null) for doing what if null value appears.

Comment: https://taroworks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170879-Error-00004-System-NullPointerException-Attempt-to-dereference-a-null-object -------Go through this link and run your code once in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `initialize the Integer Properties`

```
public class testfor1_c {

      public testfor1_c(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) { 
          Count_u18 = 0;
          Count_1830 = 0;
          Count_g30 = 0;
          getEZRen();
      }

      public Integer Count_u18 {get; set;} // variable for people < 18
      public Integer Count_1830 {get; set;} // variable for people >=18 AND <30
      public Integer Count_g30 {get; set;} // variable for people >30

      public void getEZRen() {

         List<Einzelrisiko__c> EZRList = [SELECT Alter__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c]; // create List EZRList with the information Alter__c of all people

         for(Einzelrisiko__c EZR : EZRList) {  // Loop thru the all people

               IF(EZR.Alter__c < 18) { Count_u18++; } // if Alter__c < 18 variable Count_u18 increase
               IF(EZR.Alter__c >= 18 && EZR.Alter__c <=30) { Count_1830++; } // if Alter__c >=18 AND <=30 variable Count_1830 increase
              IF(EZR.Alter__c > 30) { Count_g30++; } // if Alter__c > 30 variable Count_g30 increase
         }
      }
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I still get the error, please take a look below to my post below.